# WindowsAppSDK: How to add new items to the custom control field?

Tags: c#, windows-app-sdk

I have a custom control with a collection-type field.
When i run the app in debug mode and try to add items to the field, the XAML editor show the error:

> Error XHR0015 Failed to add HelloItem to ObservableCollection`1.
> Unable to find element.

[image]

Why the error? How to solve the problem?

The source code: https://github.com/jhonToni/CustomComponentApp

Comment: According to the source code, I couldn't reproduce the issue. Could you please try your code again? And please provide a sample that reproduces the issue?

Comment: The issue occurs when i start the debug and i go to add a new HelloItem in XAML editor in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't add a new HelloItem in XAML editor in runtime. After you add a new HelloItem, you need to recompile it.